# Passing gl_ClipDistance through shader stages. How and where to redefine gl_PerVertex?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to implement clip planes in my shaders (OpenGL 3.3). I evaluate clip planes in the vertex shader, then pass data to the geometry shader. The docs state that I need to redefine the struct gl_PerVertex with the correct amount of clip distances I'm using, but I'm at loss about where and  how, and how discarding fragments actually happens...

It makes sense for the vertex shader:

```
out gl_PerVertex {
    vec4 gl_Position;
    float gl_ClipDistance[6];
} <NAME_NEEDED?>;
```

But: Do I need to name the struct? What happens if not? Must the name be the default "gl_out"?

In the geometry shader:

```
in gl_PerVertex {
    vec4 gl_Position;
    float gl_ClipDistance[6];
} <NAME_NEEDED?>;

out gl_PerVertex {
    vec4 gl_Position;
    float gl_ClipDistance[6];
} <NAME_NEEDED?>;
```

Again: Do I need to name the struct? What happens if not? Must the name be the default "gl_in[]" and "gl_out"?

Finally: What do I need to do in the fragment shader? Are the fragements automatically discarded or do I need to test and discard in the fragment shader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, that's not a struct. It is an [interface block](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)).

Second, whether you need an instance name depends on which `gl_PerVertex` you are redeclaring. You must use the correct instance name for the particular input/output interface block for that shader stage. Here's a list:

- Vertex Shader output:

  - No instance name.
- Tessellation Control Shader input

  - `gl_in`, arrayed.
- TCS output

  - `gl_out`, arrayed.
- Tessellation Evaluation Shader input

  - `gl_in`, arrayed.
- TES output

  - No instance name.
- Geometry Shader input

  - `gl_in`, arrayed.
- Geometry Shader output:

  - No instance name.

---

> What do I need to do in the fragment shader? Are the fragements automatically discarded or do I need to test and discard in the fragment shader?

All of the `gl_` variables in OpenGL are, eventually, tied to some fixed-function apparatus. When executing the last Vertex Processing shader stage, the output `gl_*` variables are used by specific parts of the implementation. And all of the `gl_*` input variables in the Fragment Shader ultimately are generated by some process.

And `gl_ClipDistance` is no exception. It exists to tie directly into [distance-based clipping](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Clip_Distance), which is a fixed-function process. It happens before the FS is executed. You have to enable the clip distances you intend to use with `glEnable(GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0 + i);`.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I've read the interface blocks docs, but imo they lack in that department. Could you please elaborate on how to name the GS shader output?

Comment: @Bim: GS info added.

Comment: Thanks. I found out just 5 mins ago... This is important, as the Nvidia driver (K3100M, recent version) will throw an error if you use "gl_out" in the GS and reports "gl_out is not accessible in this profile". The Intel driver (HD4600, older version) does not complain, but shows rendering artifacts. Probably a compiler bug.

Comment: Note that the specs do not allow you to redeclare interface blocks in #version 330 core. The correct way for OpenGL < 4.1 should thus be: "out float gl_ClipDistance[1];" I found this out through the [glslangValidator tool](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glslang/issues/1441)

Comment: @Bim: That would suggest that it is *impossible* in 3.30 to redeclare `gl_ClipDistance` in the GS, because both the input and the output are arrayed and are defined to be within the `gl_in/out` interface block. Can you find a genuine quote from the GLSL specification that corroborates this?

Comment: The [specs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.3.30.pdf) state in 3.7 that it is usally an error redeclaring anythin stating with "gl_". 7.1 say gl_ClipDistance should be redeclared, but says nothing about the interface block. 7.6 has an example for compatibility where a variable from an interface block is redeclared and it states " The redeclaration of gl_TexCoord is done at global scope ... which is the same way it was done in previous releases", but also "This treatment is a special case forgl_TexCoord[], not a general method  for redeclaring members of blocks".

Comment: This is just to say: I'm NOT sure what's correct :). The specs are pretty mute about the topic imo...    
About the redeclaration problem: You you are correct there. It would not be possible to use in / out gl_ClipDistance simultaneously. You would have to move the clip distance calculation to the geometry shader or pass a variable...